# How to import mysql connection in another file in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am not able to import the mysql connection file from the parent file to another file for making a DB connection.

I can connect to DB if the query is written in same file, if i try to hit the same query in another file then i get "TypeError: connection.query is not a function" error. Not able to access any functions of the connection object.

this is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var mysql = require('mysql');
app = express(),
app.use(cors()),
port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: '<DB name>'
}
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

connection.connect(function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
    }
    console.log('connected successfully to DB.');
});


var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app);
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
app.listen(port);

module.exports= connection;
```

This is my api.js file:

```
'use strict';
var connection = require('../../server.js');

connection.query ('select * from <table name>', function(error, results){
    if (results){
        console.log(results);
    }
    else{
        console.log(error);
    }
});
or
exports.get=function(req,res){
        console.log(req.query.printerModel);
        console.log('inside get function');
        connection.query('select * from inkdetails', function(error, results){
            if (results){
                res.status(200).send(inkdetails)
                console.log(results);
            }
            else{
                res.status(400).send(error)
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Does your code output ''todo list RESTful API server started on: 3001' before 'connected successfully to DB.'?

Comment: Can u log what is `connection` in `api.js` file? It seems connection object is not yet exported before you are registering your routes and handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file which will handle connection and export required utility functions related to `mysql` and then you can initialize connection in your startup file and import that connection object in any handler.

your `mysql` lib:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const logger = require('your-looger-path');
const mysqlConfig = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: '<DB name>'
}

var pool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);

module.exports.connect = function (cb) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
      connection.on('error', function (err) {
        logger.error('MySQL error event', err)
      });
      connection.on('close', function (err) {
        logger.warn('MySQL close event', err)
      });
    });
    resolve()
  })
}

async function executeQuery (query) {
  logger.debug(`query: `, query)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      pool.query(query, (e, r, f) => {
        if(e){
          reject(e)
        }
        else{
          logger.debug(r,f)
          resolve(r[0])
        }
      });
    }
    catch(ex){
      reject(ex)
    }
  })  
}

async function execSP(spName, params){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      var paramPlaceHolder = ''
      if(params && params.length){
        for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
          paramPlaceHolder += '?,'
        }
      }
      if(paramPlaceHolder.length){
        paramPlaceHolder = paramPlaceHolder.slice(0, -1)
      }
      logger.debug('final SP call', `CALL ${spName}(${params})`)
      pool.query(`CALL ${spName}(${paramPlaceHolder})`, params, (e, r, f) => {
        if(e){
          reject(e)
        }
        else{
          resolve(r[0])
        }
      });
    }
    catch(ex){
      reject(ex)
    }
  })
}
module.exports.executeQuery = executeQuery
module.exports.execSP = execSP
```

and then create the connection in `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var mysqllib = require('require to your mysql wrapper created above');
app = express(),
app.use(cors()),
port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mysqllib.connect().then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to mysql...')
  var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
  routes(app);
  console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
  app.listen(port);

}).catch(e => {
  console.error('Error connecting mysql...')
  process.exit()
})
```

In your controller

```
'use strict';
const mysqlLib = require('your mysql lib path')

exports.get = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query.printerModel);
  console.log('inside get function');
  mysqlLib.executeQuery('select * from inkdetails').then((d) => {
    console.log(d);
    res.status(200).send(d)
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Sorry, something went wrong!')
  })
};
```

Hopes this help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, will try it and let you know the results.

Comment: @vikranth I have updated the answer to export other functions as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, its working now. But i had a query: why wouldn't the exporting of connection function work??

Answer (score 4):

create a config folder and create a file databaseConfig.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

config = {
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: '<DB name>'
}
var connection =mysql.createConnection(config); //added the line
connection.connect(function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
  }
  console.log('connected successfully to DB.');
});

module.exports ={
     connection : mysql.createConnection(config) 
}
```

> app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
app = express(),
app.use(cors()),
port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app);
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
app.listen(port);
```

> controller.js

```
var config = require('../../databaseConfig.js');
var connection= config.connection
connection.query ('select * from <table name>', function(error, results){
   if (results){
     console.log(results);
   }
   else{
     console.log(error);
   }
});
```

Comment: @narenda: I tried your approach too, but in database.js file i am getting "ReferenceError: connection is not defined"

Comment: @vikranth missed the one line before the connection.connect, sry for that but now i have added the line and edited the code you can have a look, have a good day

Comment: your welcome @vikranth , you can mark the answer as correct if you feel that work for you so that other while find it easy